# React JS when click menu button, entire page shift right

Tags: reactjs, wireframe

I need your suggestion. I want to develop website in React JS. For start I draw a wireframe. I'm planning to use react libraries if possible. Below is my wireframe. Can I know for a start, what I should search. The 1st image will be the UI. When I click the hamburger button, the page will slide right as shown in 2nd image. Please help  guys

Image 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNasT.png)

Image 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Aqq.png)

Comment: Learn css "Transform" with "scale, translate, rotate, ...", then you should be able to do it

Comment: thanks alot ya for this idea i need a starting point but no idea what to search for. thx for giving a hint. appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you will need to consider:

1. Storing and toggling the open/close state of your sidebar
2. The layout of your DOM elements
3. The transformation of your page content

Here's a sandbox to help you out: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-napier-s8gs09?file=/src/App.js

Comment: that is fast. can share how you do it ya. want to research furthers on this. i'm new to react but willing to learn